# How to put stuff in a hash map and use new instances with the same value of fields to get the corresponding value

Tags: java, android, dictionary, value-type

I am developing an android app to help little kids learn maths. It will display some questions and the user can answer them. At the start page there would be some options to choose from. For example, the number of digits and the operation type (i.e. +, -, *, +/-) and whether the timer is enabled. So I created a `QuestionOptions` class.

```
public class QuestionOptions implements Parcelable{
    protected QuestionOptions(Parcel in) {
        digitCount = in.readInt ();
    }

    public static final Creator<QuestionOptions> CREATOR = new Creator<QuestionOptions> () {
        @Override
        public QuestionOptions createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new QuestionOptions (in);
        }

        @Override
        public QuestionOptions[] newArray(int size) {
            return new QuestionOptions[size];
        }
    };

    public QuestionOptions (OperationType operationType, int digitCount, boolean timerEnabled) {
        this.operationType = operationType;
        this.digitCount = digitCount;
        this.timerEnabled = timerEnabled;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeParcelable (this, flags);
    }

    public enum OperationType {
        ADDITION,
        SUBTRACTION,
        ADD_AND_SUB,
        MULTIPLICATION
    }

    public boolean isTimerEnabled() {
        return timerEnabled;
    }

    public void setTimerEnabled(boolean timerEnabled) {
        this.timerEnabled = timerEnabled;
    }

    public OperationType getOperationType() {
        return operationType;
    }

    public void setOperationType(OperationType operationType) {
        this.operationType = operationType;
    }

    public int getDigitCount() {
        return digitCount;
    }

    public void setDigitCount(int digitCount) {
        this.digitCount = digitCount;
    }

    private OperationType operationType;
    private int digitCount;
    private boolean timerEnabled;
}
```

Note that I implement Parcelable because I want to send it to another activity.
So far so good. But then I want to add a feature to give prizes to the user. Now I found some pictures online to be the trophies and stuff. Here's how i want them to work: For each possible question option, there is a different prize. After some calculations, I found out there are 22 possible question options! So I decided to use a hashmap to store the possible question options (key) and the resource id of the pictures of the trophies (value).

Because this is the first time I use a hash map, I did some experiments with it and soon found out that I can't use it.

The `HashMap.get` method compares the references of the question options not the fields inside it. Here is my test:

```
HashMap<QuestionOptions, Integer> map = new HashMap<> ();
map.put(new QuestionOptions (QuestionOptions.OperationType.ADDITION, 
            1, false), 0);
map.put(new QuestionOptions (QuestionOptions.OperationType.ADDITION, 
            2, false), 1);
map.put(new QuestionOptions (QuestionOptions.OperationType.ADDITION, 
            3, false), 2);
System.out.println (map.get(
            new QuestionOptions(QuestionOptions.OperationType.ADDITION, 
            1, false)));
```

And it prints "null"...

After all that reading, you guys must be asleep... I just want to ask:

**How to put all the possible question options in a hash map and use new instances to get them out or is there another way to achieve the requirement? If yes, how?**

Comment: QuestionOptions must override equals and hash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement hashcode() and equals() methods of QuestionOptions. As you said

> The HashMap.get method compares the references.

That's the default implemetnation of [hashCode()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) method which is used by the HashMap to compare the keys

You can read more about [hashCode and equals method here](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074996/hashcode-and-equals-method-in-java-object---a-pragmatic-concept.html)

Comment: You mean I should have different hashcodes for each possible question option?

Comment: @Tarun Gupta But if he uses a new instance as key to get a particular value, how will that work? That new operator creates another new memory address. right??

Comment: No, what I mean is that if two different objects have same attribute values, the hashCode generated by these two should be the same. This can be achieved by overriding the hashCode and equals method both.

Comment: Oh yes! it worked! Thanks! Just one more quick question, why do I need to override both equals and hashCode to make it work? HashMap.get() calls both of them?

Comment: It's a good question, this should be done as part of not violating the contract between hashCode and equals method. As the Java doc says : "If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result."

Comment: Ok I see. Thanks again!